# radio button group horizontal display multi lines in XPages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, radio-group

Here is the code for a horizontal radio button:

```
<xp:radioGroup id="appType"
                                value="#{ruleDoc.AppType}" layout="lineDirection">
                                <xp:selectItem
                                    itemLabel="Applications">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem
                                    itemLabel="Lotus Notes DB">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem
                                    itemLabel="Lotus Notes Groups">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Folders"></xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Hardware"></xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Other"></xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Server"></xp:selectItem>
                            </xp:radioGroup>
```

But the display is ugly:

[image]

I would like to display them on two lines of 3 values per line. Easy to do in Native Notes but I can't figure out a way to do it in XPages.
Any ideas? I have done some searching but the solutions seem way to complicated.

Comment: May be this can help you, http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-87B5ZJ

Comment: @Frank that works great -- exactly what I was looking for not sure why it did not come up in the search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works 100% http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-87B5ZJ Stephan Wissel has some really great stuff on his blog. My search did not show this up, but then ....
I found that the radio button and the Text would run together on occassions so I modified the  tag to add some padding to the right of the text and this works well.